# Kotlin: universal data type in HashMap?

Tags: kotlin

I have some Hash Maps of some objects `<String, Object>`, some goes like this:

```java
val mapA = HashMap<String, A>
val mapB = HashMap<String, B>
val mapC = HashMap<String, C>
```

I want to create a function that takes any Hash Map to print it out. This is what I mean:

```java
fun printHashMap(hashMap: HashMap<String, (any type here, for example A, B or C)>){
    // print each element of hashmap
}
```

What I've tried so far:

```java
fun printHashMap(hashMap: HashMap<Any, Any>){
   // print HashMap here
}
```

But it throws me `Type mismatch`, `<Any, Any>` vs `<String, A>` for example.
Is this possible in Kotlin?

Comment: Are your hash map always has String as key in map?
You can change type to hashMap: HashMap<String, Any>

Comment: It still tells me that type mismatch, and suggests me to change to `<String, A>`, but I want it to apply to any value's type.

Comment: Try to change specification to `HashMap<String, *>`

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! You can write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need specific print format, you can print hashMap without your own function:

```
val testMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
testMap["1"] = 1
testMap["2"] = "2"
print(testMap)
```

Otherwise, you should change your signature of method to

```
fun printHashMap(map: Map<String, *>)
```

In functions better to use Interface instead of concrete class. And instead of Any you need to use star-projections. It is the safe way here is to define such a projection of the generic type, that every concrete instantiation of that generic type would be a subtype of that projection.

You can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) and [here](https://typealias.com/guides/star-projections-and-how-they-work/)